# when copying strings from one text file to another, the last line in the original file is not copied

Tags: c, while-loop, text-files, rename, feof

**edit: change the code to my real code, because i was told that the shortened one i posted couldn't be compiled. hope it helps in finding the problem**

i have a struct as below:

```
struct patient {
    char name[30], ID[8];
    int age, phoneNo;
};
```

and i've written the code below:

```
int searchName()
{
    char search[30];
    char record[60];
    const char s[2] = ",";
    struct patient c;
    int foundRecord = 0, linectr = 0;
    char a[8], str[200], tempname[] = "tempfile.txt", filename[] = "patient.txt";
    int IDno, temp = 999999;

    FILE* fPtr, *fPtr2;
    fPtr = fopen(filename, "r");

    printf("Enter name to to replace phoneNo with 999999: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(search, 30, stdin);

    //remove the '\n' at the end of string
    search[strcspn(search, "\n")] = 0;

    printf("Record found: ");

    while (fgets(record, 60, fPtr))
    {
        // strstr returns start address of substring in case if present
        if (strstr(record, search))
        {
            char* pStr = strtok(record, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                strcpy(c.ID, pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                strcpy(c.name, pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.age = atoi(pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.phoneNo = atoi(pStr);
            }
            printf("\n%s\t%s\t%d\t%d", c.ID, c.name, c.age, c.phoneNo);
            foundRecord++;
        }

    }
    if (foundRecord = 0)
        printf("%s cannot be found\n", search);
    
    strcpy(a, c.ID);
    sscanf(a, "PT%d", &IDno);

    fPtr = fopen(filename, "r");

    fPtr2 = fopen(tempname, "w");

    while (!feof(fPtr))
    {
        strcpy(str, "\0");
        fgets(str, 100, fPtr);
        if (!feof(fPtr))
        {
            linectr++;
            if (linectr != IDno)
            {
                fprintf(fPtr2, "%s", str);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fPtr2, "%s,%s,%d,%d\n", c.ID, c.name, c.age, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fPtr);
    fclose(fPtr2);
    remove(filename);
    rename(tempname, filename);
    printf("\nReplacement successful. \n");
    return 0;
}
```

the code works like this: i have a bunch of strings in a text file called `patient.txt`, and i want to replace a string (`IDno`) in the text file with a string i have stored in `struct patient c` prior to this. the code works in creating another file and copying strings from the original file (`patient.txt`) into a new file while replacing the original string with the the new string, but i noticed that the last string in the original file always gets ignored. for example, i have 6 lines below stored in the original file:

```
PT1,John Doe,35,123456
PT2,Mary Ann,34,124684
PT3,John Lemmons,15,834945
PT4,James Bond,22,565453
PT5,Mary Sue,34,3435453
PT6,John Brown,54,3435346
```

when i search for Mary Ann to be replaced (line 2), only the first 5 lines (including the replaced 2nd line) get copied into the new file when i run my code. why is the last line not being copied? another issue is that the `remove` and `rename` functions in my code isn't working and i'm not sure why. would appreciate it if someone could explain how i can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `feof` is most likely the problem, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/6865932), you can create a much simpler and effective while cycle using `fgets` return value as a stop condition:

```
while (fgets(str, 100, fPtr)) //when file ends stop
{
    linectr++;
    if (linectr != IDno)
    {
        fprintf(fPtr2, "%s", str);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(fPtr2, "%s,%s,%d,%d\n", c.ID, c.name, c.age, temp);
    }
}
```

---

There is also  typo in `if (foundRecord = 0)`, it should be `==`, that is most certainly derailing your program.

---

Comment: @cmy, you have a typo in `if (foundRecord = 0)` should be `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all your `while (!feof(fPtr))` loop with this:

```
    while (fgets(str, 100, fPtr) != NULL)
    {
        linectr++;
        if (linectr != IDno)
        {
            fprintf(fPtr2, "%s", str);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(fPtr2, "%s,%s,%d,%d\n", c.ID, c.name, c.age, temp);
        }
    }
```

There may be other problems though.

Off topic remarks:

- you should check if `fopen` fails which actually happens very often in the real world.
- drop the `[15]` in `char tempname[15] = "tempfile.txt"` -> `char tempname[] = "tempfile.txt"`

Comment: thank you so much for the help! i've dropped the `[15]` in both `tempname[]` and `filename[]` and checked for `fopen` failure with `if(!fPtr)`, but there were no issues. not sure why the `remove` and `rename` functions are still not working..